# Using premium emoji on telethon

Tags: python, telegram, emoji, telethon, aiogram

I have a telegram bot with which the user enters text for sending, and the telethon client sends messages with this text (not spam). But, I encountered a problem: premium emoji are converted into regular ones (even if the client has Telegram Premium on his account). I came across a post in the documentation:

```
from telethon.extensions import markdown
from telethon import types

class CustomMarkdown:
    @staticmethod
    def parse(text):
        text, entities = markdown.parse(text)
        for i, e in enumerate(entities):
            if isinstance(e, types.MessageEntityTextUrl):
                if e.url == 'spoiler':
                    entities[i] = types.MessageEntitySpoiler(e.offset, e.length)
                elif e.url.startswith('emoji/'):
                    entities[i] = types.MessageEntityCustomEmoji(e.offset, e.length, int(e.url.split('/')[1]))
        return text, entities
    @staticmethod
    def unparse(text, entities):
        for i, e in enumerate(entities or []):
            if isinstance(e, types.MessageEntityCustomEmoji):
                entities[i] = types.MessageEntityTextUrl(e.offset, e.length, f'emoji/{e.document_id}')
            if isinstance(e, types.MessageEntitySpoiler):
                entities[i] = types.MessageEntityTextUrl(e.offset, e.length, 'spoiler')
        return markdown.unparse(text, entities)

client.parse_mode = CustomMarkdown()
client.send_message('me', 'hello this is a [hidden text](spoiler), with custom emoji [❤️](emoji/10002345) !')
```

Accordingly, when using such emoji, the user must enter them in the form `[❤️](emoji/10002345)`, which in my opinion is a big bummer.

I would like to automatically convert the premium emoji entered into the bot, but I don’t want to use something like:

```
emojies = {
    "❤️": 10002345,
    . . .
}
my_emodji = emojies['❤️']
```

A large number of emoji packs will be used and this method is not the most effective. Tell me, how can I automate receiving emoji id?

---

I tried to use `<emoji id=айди_эмодзи>any emoji</emoji>` but again, the question arises with getting emoji ID.
There are similar threads on Stackoverflow, but they don't answer my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send premiume-emoji with telethon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76024878/send-premiume-emoji-with-telethon)

Comment: get all of them via https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_emoji_keywords.html#examples

Comment: The topic on stackoverflow doesn’t suit me, but here it explains how to use emoji, and I need to automate getting their id. I'll try your second link and post if it helps me

Comment: I get a list of standard emoji, not premium and without their id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave this post as an answer in case anyone needs this information in the future.

```
text = "[](emoji/5388790256772331442)"

me = await client.get_me()
access_hash = me.access_hash

# search premium emoji in your text
prem_emoji = await client(functions.messages.SearchCustomEmojiRequest(
    emoticon=text,
    hash=access_hash
))
emoji_ids = prem_emoji.document_id # Premium emoji ids
    
# return EmojiObject
emojies = await client(functions.messages.GetCustomEmojiDocumentsRequest(
    document_id=emoji_ids
))
logging.info(emojies)
```