# Telegram Premium emojis + api

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, emoji, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to send a premium emoji via Python Telebot

using the entities field and the following code:

```
ent = MessageEntity('custom_emoji',0,2,custom_emoji_id =  '5460965296690960473')
entities = [ent]
bot.send_message('753786861','',entities=entities)
```

but I'm not getting the desired result. How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77901455/using-premium-emoji-on-telethon